# Where do the created_at and updated_at columns come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

All the tables in the database created by a rails application seem to have created_at and updated_at columns.  What creates these?  Are they optional, or does something internal rely on them?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They are created by default when you run the ActiveRecord migration for a model. ActiveRecord automatically populates/updates them when you create or update a model instance (and thus the underlying database table row) respectively.

You can remove the columns by removing the `t.timestamps` line from within the model migration file.

- [Ruby on Rails Guides: Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

Comment: is their any way we can rename it to say created_ts may be?

Comment: @rajansoft1 there is not, the names are hardcoded -- although you can use `created_on`/`updated_on` instead of `created_at`/`updated_at` if you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

In your database migration for every table you have something like `t.timestamps`. Remove this from your migration and your database columns created_at and updated_at  won't be created.

Edit:

In case you need to create a new migration to remove those columns you can use
[remove_timestamps](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_timestamps) or [remove_column](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_column)

`remove_timestamps` definition shows how you can use `remove_column` if you want to.

```
def remove_timestamps(table_name, **options)
  remove_column table_name, :updated_at
  remove_column table_name, :created_at
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Octopus said, they are optional and are used to track the record creation and updating date time in the corresponding tables.