# How to make an sqlite3 database without default fields?

Tags: ruby, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do the created_at and updated_at columns come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722785/where-do-the-created-at-and-updated-at-columns-come-from)

Every time I use `db:migrate`, my table creates fine, with the expected fields, but it also has the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns, which I don't want and didn't include anywhere in my migration.  How can I remove them, or better yet, how can I create tables in the future without these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the columns by removing the `t.timestamps` line from within the model migration file.